# T-SQL conditional alias for count(*) column in a group by query

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a stored proc that accepts a single @status parameter, which is used in the where-clause:

```
        ... where status = @status
```

The query is grouped:

```
          col1, col2, col3, count(*) as __________
          where status=@status
          group by col1, col2, col3
```

The results are exported by users to an Excel spreadsheet.  Since they do many of these exports, they're wondering if the column alias for the `count(*)` column change according go the value passed in the @status parameter.

```
          count (*) as "A status"
```

I know it can be done by making the entire query a string and doing `exec(s)`. Is there any other way?

Comment: If the column alias will depend on the parameter you either use dynamic SQL or had every possible value of `@status` predefined and use different `IF`s

Comment: Identifiers are not data in SQL; as such they cannot be bound with variables or expressions. Anyway, my recommendation would be to give it the name 'status' and then rename it externally (eg. in the DataTable) if such is possible. Dynamic SQL would work, but .. ick.